# iphone - notification

Tags: iphone, notifications

I am new iPhone developer,

Can anybody suggest me what should i do here:

I have built an App in which i am finding how far the user from end location or a goal, So I have a given range (`nearBy`) here, if the user came within the range , he/she got a message or alert.

My question is how can notify the user? how could I show that message?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`UILocalNotification`***

> Instances of UILocalNotification represent notifications that an application can schedule for presentation to its users at specific dates and times. The operating system is responsible for delivering the notification at the proper time; the application does not have to be running for this to happen. Although local notifications are similar to remote notifications in that they are used for displaying alerts, playing sounds, and badging application icons, they are composed and delivered locally and do not require connection with remote servers.

You should take a look at [UILocalNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: but if i want to display specific message like if user in range then "You Are In Range" and when he/she come out from range then "You Are Out Of Range" then?

Comment: @user687732: Yah that's exactly what you can do with `UILocalNotification`, you can start thinking like `I need to recursively check the user location, not necessarily every 1 sec and show an UIAlertView with the correct message, you need to keep your app Quick and light as possible`.